# Entity Framework: deleted SQL table is not removed from the model

Tags: entity-framework

Seemingly simple thing got me completely frozen and I can't find anything on the Net about this:

I had a common many to many relationship in my db:

Table One + TableTwo + LinkingTable with 2 columns: TableOneID and TableTwoID

I deleted the LinkingTable and tried to update the model from database. Now I get error "Error 11007: Entity type 'LinkingTable' is not mapped."

Does anyone know what exactly this EF wants? Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Right-click the Model in the Solution Explorer. Select "Open with..." Select "XML (Text) Editor" in the dialog. Remove all nodes and references of the LinkingTable (or whatever its real name is) from the model's xml. Close all model files that are currently opened (I know, weird). Build the project. Open the model again. Everything should be fine now.

Comment: It worked, thanks! I'm new to EF and I inherited this model from prev programmer. Why this happens?

Comment: I don't know the exact inners of all entity framework's "wizards" and stuff in terms of many to many relationships. But I know from experience that the only way to fix many-to-many issues is to manually AND CAREFULLY edit model's xml. At least for now, until MS fixes this stuff. So, if "delete" operation didn't get propagated, just delete all references to that table manually and reload the model. Something like that :)

Comment: thanks for this - I have exactly the same problem. Manually correcting the XML seems to be the easiest solution.

Comment: thank you very much! MS could've at least mentioned this workaround until (or if) they fix this..

Answer (score 1):

Open Model Browser,
In the Entity types, select the table which is to be deleted,
It will remove all the associations with the table.

It worked well for me.